# Is there any way to share a google colab pro account with somoene else without sharing Google credentials?

Tags: python, deep-learning, google-colaboratory, training-data

Someone I know already has a Google Colab Pro account and I need to use it for a while for training a deep learning model. Can he/she *lend* their account to me without sharing Google credentials? I know this can be done in Gmail but dont know if it can be done with Colab Pro, or if so, how. TIA

Comment: It is **currently** not possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can share the colab file, but you cannot share the accounts among a team or something.
**So to simply answer that question, that is not possible.**
Hope this helps.